# Json request en WebApi c#

Tags: c#, json, webapi

Estoy intentando desarrollar una Webapi que recibe un Json en el cuerpo. El Json es de este tipo:

```
{
"SubscriberKey":"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbccccccc",
"Digito_Verificador":"1",
"Motivo":"Cliente interesado", 
"Fecha":"2020-05-05",
"Hora":"10:26:54",
"Id_Oportunidad":"as125y" 

"Contacto":[
{"Campo":"Nombre", "Valor":"Sebastian"},
{"Campo":"Apellido_Paterno", "Valor":"Contreras"},
{"Campo":"Apellido_Materno", "Valor":"Aguilera"},
{"Campo":"Email", "Valor":"email@gmail.com"},
{"Campo":"Telefono_Movil", "Valor":"912345678"},
{"Campo":"Segmento", "Valor":"Gold"},
{"Campo":"Sexo", "Valor":"H"},
{"Campo":"flg_tcwm", "Valor":1},
{"Campo":"flg_tcplatinum", "Valor":1},
{"Campo":"flg_tcgold", "Valor":1},
{"Campo":"FLg_Cta_Cte_mn", "Valor":1},
{"Campo":"flg_Seguro_Vida", "Valor":0},
{"Campo":"flg_Seguro_Auto", "Valor":0},
{"Campo":"flg_Seguro_Hogar", "Valor":0},
{"Campo":"flg_Seguro_Salud", "Valor":1}
],

"Solicitud":[
{"Campo":"Vigencia_Vta", "Valor":"31/01/2020"},
{"Campo":"Tipo_Seguro", "Valor":"Dato cualquiera"}
]
}
```

Estoy teniendo problemas en capturar lo que viene desde el nodo "Contacto" en adelante. Estoy muy perdido en como es la mejor forma de tener todos esos datos. Espero que me puedan orientar. Gracias de antemano

Comment: Saludos. Le sugiero colocar el mensaje de error que se le muestra o lo que está ocurriendo que implica los "problemas en capturar" el y los nodos `Contacto` en adelante.

Answer (score 0):

Hola esto se hace usando el paquete de Utf8Json (es más rápido que el famoso NewtonSoft) esta es la comparación: https://github.com/neuecc/Utf8Json (Está en inglés pero la tabla lo dice todo.)

```
    value = @"{
    "SubscriberKey":"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbccccccc",
    "Digito_Verificador":"1",
    "Motivo":"Cliente interesado", 
    "Fecha":"2020-05-05",
    "Hora":"10:26:54",
    "Id_Oportunidad":"as125y" 
    
    "Contacto":[
    {"Campo":"Nombre", "Valor":"Sebastian"},
    {"Campo":"Apellido_Paterno", "Valor":"Contreras"},
    {"Campo":"Apellido_Materno", "Valor":"Aguilera"},
    {"Campo":"Email", "Valor":"email@gmail.com"},
    {"Campo":"Telefono_Movil", "Valor":"912345678"},
    {"Campo":"Segmento", "Valor":"Gold"},
    {"Campo":"Sexo", "Valor":"H"},
    {"Campo":"flg_tcwm", "Valor":1},
    {"Campo":"flg_tcplatinum", "Valor":1},
    {"Campo":"flg_tcgold", "Valor":1},
    {"Campo":"FLg_Cta_Cte_mn", "Valor":1},
    {"Campo":"flg_Seguro_Vida", "Valor":0},
    {"Campo":"flg_Seguro_Auto", "Valor":0},
    {"Campo":"flg_Seguro_Hogar", "Valor":0},
    {"Campo":"flg_Seguro_Salud", "Valor":1}
    ],
    
    "Solicitud":[
    {"Campo":"Vigencia_Vta", "Valor":"31/01/2020"},
    {"Campo":"Tipo_Seguro", "Valor":"Dato cualquiera"}
    ]
    }";
    
    Dictionary<string, object> json = Utf8Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(value);

string Contacto = "";
if (json.TryGetValue("Contacto", out object objContact))
{
  Contacto = (string)objContact;
}
else
{
  Contacto = null;
}
```